# Oracle (pl-sql) - how to extract particular data from text into object type variable?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have text provided as varchar2 variable, for exameple:

```
EXER/ATP-45/-//
MSGID/BIOCHEM3/-/-/-/-/-//
GEODATUM/UTM//
PAPAA/1KM/-//15KM/-//
```

So, every line separator is // (but there can be also spaces, new lines etc and they should be ignored). '-' is indicating blank field and should be ignored. I have also defined new object type, defined as follows:

```
TYPE t_promien      IS RECORD(
EXER                VARCHAR2,
MSGID               VARCHAR2(1000),
PAPAA               t_papaa
......
)
```

I need to extract data from corresponding rows into new variable that has t_promien type and set its field, for example - EXER should has 'ATP-45' value, MSGID should has 'BIOCHEM3', PAPAA should has ('1KM','15KM') value (t_papaa is my custom type too and it contains 2 varchar fields).

What is the best way to do this inside oracle PL-SQL procedure? I need to extract needed data into out parameter. Can I use regex for this (how?) Ufortunatelly, I'm totally newbie with oracle, so...

Can you give me some tips? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? The regex features vary between releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` using something like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('EXER/ATP-45/-//
MSGID/BIOCHEM3/-/-/-/-/-//
GEODATUM/UTM//
PAPAA/1KM/-//15KM/-//', 'EXER/[^/]+/', 1, 1) AS EXER
FROM DUAL;
```

The important bit above is `'EXER/[^/]+/'` which is looking for a string that starts with the literal `EXER/` followed be a sequence of characters which are not `/` and ended by a final `/`.

The above query will return `EXER/ATP-45/`, but you can use standard string functions like `SUBSTR`, `LTRIM` or `RTRIM` to remove the bits you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

A simple demonstration of the use of REGEXP_SUBSTR in PL/SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_REGEXP_PROC(VAR_PI_MSG IN VARCHAR2,
                                             T_PO_PAPAA OUT T_PROMIEN) AS

  VAR_L_EXER  VARCHAR2(1000);
  VAR_L_MSGID VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

  SELECT SUBSTR(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAR_PI_MSG, 'EXER/[^/]+/', 1, 1),'/'),5)
    INTO VAR_L_EXER
    FROM DUAL;

  T_PO_PAPAA.EXER := VAR_L_EXER;

  SELECT SUBSTR(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAR_PI_MSG, 'MSGID/[^/]+/', 1, 1),'/'),6)
    INTO VAR_L_MSGID
    FROM DUAL;

  T_PO_PAPAA.MSGID := VAR_L_MSGID;  

END;
```

Hope this will get you started.